# background-image and sites.php

Tags: files, multi-sites

I have a multisite configuration with Drupal7, my prod site is `mysite.example.mydomain.com` and dev is `mysitedev.example.mydomain.com` I have set in `sites/sites.php` :

`$sites = array('mysite.example.mydomain.com' => 'mysitedev.example.mydomain.com',
);`

so searching for `sites/mysite.example.mydomain.com` would result as `sites/mysite.dev`. example `mydomain.com`, but I have a background Image Url:

`background: url("/sites/mysite.example.mydomain.com/files/myimage.jpg");`

if the Url is `/sites/mysitedev.example.mydomain.com/files` it works, otherwise with `/sites/mysite.example.mydomain.com/files` it don't! 
What am I missing???

Thanks.

Comment: Look at your directory structure in `sites/`. If your production site is in folder "default" then you would put:
`'mysite.example.mydomain.com' => 'default'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're confusing hostnames with file system paths.

The array mapping in sites.php is:

```
Hostname => Instance Folder
```

So taking your example, requests for http://mysite.example.mydomain.com will use the folder /sites/mysitedev.example.mydomain.com.

In that scenario, the path /sites/mysite.example.mydomain.com/files doesn't exist, so requests for files under it will return a 404. That's to be expected.

You can always add an alias/redirect via your server config, but it might be best to just use the system as it was intended.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but in this way i should change every url in css files? or make a symlink from /sites/mysitedev.example.mydomain.com to /sites/mysite.example.mydomain.com?

Comment: In an ideal world your CSS should never depend on files inside the files folder. A theme needs to be able to stand on its own, and not rely on content that may or may not have been uploaded